# How to reduce apk size under 100MB

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I am Unable to upload my Android APK on google play store because its actual size more than 100 MB its size is 169 MB and I need to resize it under 100 MB. Is there any solution that I can resize my APK ? so I can upload my APK on google play store.

I am also adding that code. But, only few MB reduced -

buildTypes {

```
    release {

        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config

    }

    
}
```

Comment: Did you perform "clean" before generating the build?

Comment: yes, I did it clean

Comment: [Analyze the apk](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-analyzer) , and check for what's taking the most of the size , it might be libraries or images

Comment: yes,I have to check it. It's increases size because of multiple libraries and all are used. But, how to reduces that libraries size?

Comment: Can you share which library is taking most of the size.

Comment: There are multiple libraries like agora-rtc-sdk, hbrecorder, exoplayerview, ViewPagerIndicator, ImageGesture, etc.

Comment: Are you sure these are one's taking the most  size , can you tell me your res folder size and lib folder size in analysis of apk. exoplayer, ViewPageIndicator and ImageGesture are light weight library and shouldn't increase app size.

Comment: If you use a lot of C++/JNI libraries the size could drammatically increase due to different build for arm7a, arm8, x86, etc.... Could it be your case?

Comment: yes, res folder size is 17 MB and lib folder size is 131 MB @Nitish

Comment: yes, used multiple libraries @emandt Is there any solution to reduce that lib size?

Comment: You can check in library GitHub page if there is any lightweight version of library is available or not.

Comment: Also instead of apk , generate app bundle , it will reduce the install size of the app and app bundle has upload limit of 150mb on play store

Comment: Are you building .aab file or .apk ? I you're not building .aab file try with it. It will reduce file size.

Comment: I also tried to generate app bundle. It is also exceeds 150MB size i.e.169 MB @Nitish

Comment: I also tried it @ Hafiza

Comment: You have to compile_it/include_libraries only for ONE platform (arm7a, arm8, x86, etc...) and not all together in one single APK....Or let the main APK download libraries in runtime (but you need to build them as Shared Libraries and modify your code to perform this download).

Comment: Or can need to generate [split apks](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits)

Comment: Ok, I will check it. Thanks @emandt

Answer (score 0):

The new limit is 150 MB using [app bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle)

You just have to reduce it by 20 MB and it will work.

Share your libraries and assets you are using and we can help you further.